# Can this double list comprehension go straight into an array (Is there a more Pythonic way?)

Tags: python, numpy, reduce

My goal is to write a function that performs modulo-2 multiplication of two arrays (multiplication = and, addition = xor).  Here is the code I have now.  Any suggestions about how to improve this gratefully received - in particular, should I / how can I have the list comprehension go straight into an array of the appropriate shape?

```
import numpy as np
import operator

def m2mult(a,b):

    c = np.ndarray([reduce(operator.xor, np.logical_and(a[x,:],b[:,y]))
         for x in range(0,a.shape[0]) for y in range (0, b.shape[1])])
    c.shape = (a.shape[0], b.shape[1])

    return c
```

Comment: I think itertools.imap might be of use to you here.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't do it like that at all:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,(4,4))
b = np.random.randint(0,2,(4,4))

# Now note that this is true:
# (I will let you figure that out, its a lot of neat broadcasting.
# b.T would be enough as well, because of it)
np.multiply(a[:,None,:], b.T[None,:,:]).sum(-1) == np.dot(a,b)
# note also that .sum(-1) is the same as np.add.reduce(array, axis=-1)

# now we can do the same thing for your logical operations:
a = np.random.randint(0,2,(4,4)).astype(bool)
b = np.random.randint(0,2,(4,4)).astype(bool)

def m2mult(a, b):
    mult = np.logical_and(a[:,None,:], b.T[None,:,:])
    return np.logical_xor.reduce(mult, axis=-1)
```

And its fully vectorized, much faster and just numpy!

Comment: +1 But why not `mult = np.logical_and(a[..., None], b)` and then `np.logical_xor.reduce(mult, axis=1)`? Isn't it better to spare the transposition?

Comment: @Jaime good point, I guess when trying quickly I got there because in my brain its looks a bit closer like matrix multiplication (if that is possible)

Comment: Ok then! I have a great respect for the quality of your answers, and was wondering if you were taking advantage of some mysterious optimization by doing the `reduce` over the last axis...

Answer (score 2):

You can just do common matrix multiplication on `int`s, followed by modulo-2 reduction and then convert back to `bool`:

```
np.mod(np.dot(a.astype('u1'), b), 2).astype('bool')
```

It is faster than seberg's solution and Jaime's modification to it.

```
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
|               |  10x10  | 1000x1000 | 750x1250 |
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
| m2mult_tz     | 33 us   | 7.27 s    | 4.68 s   |
| m2mult_jaime  | 56.7 us | 20.4 s    | 14.2 s   |
| m2mult_seberg | 62.9 us | 20.5 s    | 14.3 s   |
+---------------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

This might be an issue for really large arrays or if your program does this operation a lot.
I timed this approach and the solutions of seberg and the modification to it suggested by Jaime.
Here's how I implemented the different functions:

```
import numpy as np

def create_ab(n, m):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, m)).astype(bool)
    b = np.random.randint(0, 2, (m, n)).astype(bool)
    return a, b


def m2mult_tz(a, b):
    return np.mod(np.dot(a.astype('u1'), b), 2).astype(bool)


def m2mult_seberg(a, b):
    return np.logical_xor.reduce(
                np.logical_and(a[:,None,:], b.T[None,:,:]),
                axis=-1)


def m2mult_jaime(a, b):
    return np.logical_xor.reduce(
                np.logical_and(a[:, :, None], b),
                axis=1)
```

Here' a record of the 1000x1000 timings  (I also checked that results are the same in all cases):

```
In [19]: a, b = create_ab(1000, 1000)

In [20]: timeit m2mult_tz(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.27 s per loop

In [21]: timeit m2mult_jaime(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 20.4 s per loop

In [22]: timeit m2mult_seberg(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 20.5 s per loop

In [23]: r_tz = m2mult_tz(a, b)

In [24]: r_jaime = m2mult_jaime(a, b)

In [25]: r_seberg = m2mult_seberg(a, b)

In [26]: np.all(r_tz == r_jaime)
Out[26]: True

In [27]: np.all(r_tz == r_seberg)
Out[27]: True
```